How do I rotate curved text 90 degrees around the face of a coin?
I'm using Blender 4.2.0 (that just got released.) I am very new to blender.
I have extruded text and modified it to fit around a curve on the face of a cylinder (coin). No matter what I rotate though, the curve, the text, in any direction, positive or negative, I cannot get the text to start and end where I want on the circle. It curves around the left side of the coin, and I want it to curve around the top. How do I fix this?
All the answers I've seen seem to be about how to wrap the text around the curved face of a can or bottle.


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots I got my question answered, but I'm actually not sure how I would attach my blend file. I'm happy to do so. What's the usual process?

I made this file sharing guide. It isn't necessary anymore for this question, but it's good to know for next time ;)

If the way you curved the text object is by using a Curve modifier, then all you have to do is selecting both the text object and the curve, and rotate them around the curve:

If both objects have their origins aligned, it's all it takes.
